# How do I reset openvswitch to stop using "other_config" settings I set?

Tags: command-line, apt, 18.04, make

I messed up my openvswitch, and even after remove/purge with `apt`, the "other_config" parameters still appear. I have been bouncing between a compiled version of ovs with dpdk I did myself and apt. I even tried `sudo make uninstall` from the repo I built in.
The log shows as much.
How can I reset everything on openvswitch?
Keep getting these errors in the vswitch log:

```
2022-07-14T20:21:03.333Z|00016|dpdk|ERR|EAL: Invalid 'command line' arguments.
2022-07-14T20:21:03.333Z|00017|dpdk|EMER|Unable to initialize DPDK: Invalid argument
```

Is there a way I can enable debug mode in the logs? "Invalid 'command line' argument is not very clear.
Tried running `ovs-appctl vlog/set ANY:ANY:dbg` but ovs-switchd needs to be running, and I cant even start it because of dpdk errors.

Here are the commands I ran from this article:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/openvswitch-dpdk

Here is the man file on those commands:
http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-vswitchd.conf.db.5.html

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
First of all the database can be accessed and viewed with `ovsdb-client` I used this command

```
sudo ovsdb-client dump --pretty --format=csv
```

which showed the following, this table in particular

```
Open_vSwitch table
_uuid,bridges,cur_cfg,datapath_types,datapaths,db_version,dpdk_initialized,dpdk_version,external_ids,iface_types,manager_options,next_cfg,other_config,ovs_version,ssl,statistics,system_type,system_version
e2a3fa00-23c9-4c3d-b9b6-e37df4f00dd7,[d8c3b103-4822-48aa-8810-76bb2a58e652],56,"[netdev, system]",{},"""8.3.0""",true,"""DPDK 21.11.1""","{hostname=emd1, rundir=""/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch"", system-id=""f10c5ec0-bd3c-43d8-ac2a-4150041ec38b""}","[bareudp, dpdk, dpdkvhostuser, dpdkvhostuserclient, erspan, geneve, gre, gtpu, internal, ip6erspan, ip6gre, lisp, patch, stt, system, tap, vxlan]",[],61,"{dpdk-alloc-mem=""2048"", dpdk-extra=""--pci-whitelist=0000:41:01.6"", dpdk-init=""true"", dpdk-lcore-mask=""0x1""}","""2.17.2""",[],{},Ubuntu,"""18.04-bionic"""
```

I can see the entries that were causing problems. I removed them with the following commands

```
sudo ovs-vsctl remove Open_vswitch . other_config dpdk-lcore-mask
sudo ovs-vsctl remove Open_vswitch . other_config dpdk-alloc-mem
sudo ovs-vsctl remove Open_vswitch . other_config dpdk-extra
```

Then restarted the service and ovs worked again

```
sudo systemctl restart openvswitch-switch
```

Just don't understand why these settings were stuck in the database even after uninstall and purging multiple times. Maybe the database is somewhere static and is not removed after unistall?
Oh well its working now.